# The INCRBY instruction executed by a Redis pipeline return a reference to the pipeline instead the value of the key modified

Tags: python, redis, transactions, watch, redis-py

I have some problem to use Redis pipeline. I need to execute 2 commands (`incr()` and `set()`) by a *Redis transaction*.

**Environment info**: redis-py version 3.5.3; the version of the Redis server is v=5.0.5.

So I have tried to use the following code (the code example is reproducible):

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis()
pipe = r.pipeline()

def redis_insertion():
    pipe.multi()
    testIndex = pipe.incr('testIndex')
    pipe.set('new_key:' + str(testIndex), 'new_value')
    pipe.execute()
    pipe.reset()

redis_insertion()
```

By Monitor I can see the real commands executed by the redis server:

```
> redis-cli monitor
OK
1684750490.821375 [0 127.0.0.1:47322] "MULTI"
1684750490.821394 [0 127.0.0.1:47322] "INCRBY" "testIndex" "1"
1684750490.821400 [0 127.0.0.1:47322] "SET" "new_key:Pipeline<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>" "new_value"
1684750490.821411 [0 127.0.0.1:47322] "EXEC"
```

The problem is that the instruction `pipe.set('new_key:' + str(testIndex), 'new_value')` return:

```
Pipeline<ConnectionPool<Connection<host=localhost,port=6379,db=0>>>
```

instead of the value of the key `testIndex` after the execution of the `INCRBY` instruction.

Could someone explain me this behaviour?

Comment: execute returns a list of command responses, I'd expect your incr response to be the first thing in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute` function returns a list of command responses from Redis, so your  `incr` response should be the first thing in that list.

Example:

```
from redis import Redis

redis_client = Redis(decode_responses=True)

pipeline = redis_client.pipeline(transaction=False)

pipeline.incr("somekey", 1)
pipeline.set("hello", "world")
pipeline.get("hello")
responses = pipeline.execute()

print(responses)
```

Output:

```
$ python demo.py
[3, True, 'world']
```

Versions:

```
$ cat requirements.txt
async-timeout==4.0.2
redis==4.5.5
$ python --version
Python 3.10.7
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I need the value of `somekey` incremented before the execution of the `execute()` method. See the instruction `pipe.set('new_key:' + str(testIndex), 'new_value')`

Comment: That's not something that you can achieve like this.  If you need to work on the value then either get it first and watch the "somekey" key while you do your "set command", or use a Lua script that executes atomically on the redis server to perform this logic.

Answer (score 0):

By the answer of @Simon Prickett and especially thanks to his comment:

> If you need to work on the value then either get it first and watch the "somekey" key while you do your "set command", or use a Lua script that executes atomically on the redis server to perform this logic.

I have changed my code as below:

```
import redis

r = redis.Redis()
pipe = r.pipeline()

def redis_insertion():
    pipe.watch('testIndex')
    testIndex = int(r.get('testIndex'))
    pipe.multi()
    testIndex += 1
    pipe.set('testIndex', testIndex)
    pipe.set('new_key:' + str(testIndex), 'new_value')
    pipe.execute()
    pipe.reset()

redis_insertion()
```

In this case the monitor shows:

```
> redis-cli monitor
OK
1684824514.507417 [0 127.0.0.1:46494] "WATCH" "testIndex"
1684824514.507815 [0 127.0.0.1:46496] "GET" "testIndex"
1684824514.508060 [0 127.0.0.1:46494] "MULTI"
1684824514.508073 [0 127.0.0.1:46494] "SET" "testIndex" "37"
1684824514.508080 [0 127.0.0.1:46494] "SET" "new_key:37" "new_value"
1684824514.508087 [0 127.0.0.1:46494] "EXEC"
1684824514.508670 [0 127.0.0.1:46494] "GET" "testIndex"
```

The output of the monitor shows that in the Redis DB have been correctly inserted the keys:

- testIndex=37 (`"SET" "testIndex" "37"`)
- new_key:37='new_value' (`"SET" "new_key:37" "new_value"`)